# Как импортировать модуль по пути, прописанному в переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

У меня множество файлов в одной папке (модули с данными разных категорий товаров). Имя файла (модуля) должен выбираться в зависимости от категории, например, если категория "car", то имя файла "characterist_0014_car".
Я надеялся, что получится переменной присвоить путь для импорта модуля в виде строки, а потом, используя `eval()` с помощью этой переменной импортировать требующийся модуль:

```
def ajax_characterist_filterDef(request):

    category = request.GET["category"]

    path = 'from shop.models.product.characterist import characterist_0014_'+ category

    eval(path)
```

Но, вполне ожидаемо, ничего не вышло, кроме ошибки.

```
Internal Server Error: /shop/category/ajax/characterist_filter/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Google Диск\bf\shop\views\category\ajax\characterist\ajax_characterist_filter.py", line 29, in ajax_characterist_filterDef
    eval(path)
  File "<string>", line 1
    from shop.models.product.characterist import characterist_0014_pk
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Посоветуйте пожалуйста мне, и многим другим, кто не нашёл в инете ответа, как это бы решили вы.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Кст, можно импортировать еще через `importlib`, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/27e60868ba991037147b6cdc536decf59d1f30c4/html_parsing/get_game_genres/common_utils.py#L21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать не `eval`, а `exec`

`exec(path)`

Comment: нужно importlib использовать